# Argparse conditional optional positional arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

When using `argparse` I have to add an extra step to make sure there is a input (either from stdin or file).

```
import sys, argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)
args = parser.parse_args()

# taking input from stdin which is empty, so there is neither a stdin nor a file as argument
if sys.stdin.isatty() and args.infile.name == "<stdin>":
    sys.exit("Please give some input")

with args.infile as file:
    print(file.read())
```

If I use `default=(None if sys.stdin.isatty() else sys.stdin)` instead of `default=sys.stdin` , then I have to use the following `if` block to make sure there is a input (either from stdin or file):

```
if args.infile is None:
    sys.exit("Please give some input")
```

Instead of:

```
if sys.stdin.isatty() and args.infile.name == "<stdin>":
    sys.exit("Please give some input")
```

Is there anyway by using `parser.add_argument`, I can get rid of this `if` block. For example, by saying "if there is no stdin then must take one argument".

I want to get rid of this `if` block and use `parser.add_argument` only so that the help generates properly.

Comment: `required=sys.stdin.isatty()`?